# Boostrap not working when text wrapping

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

I have a form with 3 columns. The middle column is also "split" into 2 columns that on phones becomes one column.

My problem is that the middle column does not behave correctly on tablet and desktop. The fields are not aligned where they should be. It might be a browser issue.
If the browser window is maximized the last field (11th) instead of being on left it is on right.
If the browser window is shrunk the 5th field is being on the right instead of the left. This is because the 3rd field is being wrapped.

https://www.bootply.com/FgfwYKdIr0

Can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

try this it will solve your problem.

```
 label {
        white-space: nowrap;
 }
```

have fun

Comment: Have you tried this on the example that I provided? For me the 11th remain in the same place. So this is not a full solution. Plus what happens when the text is greater than the allocated space?